# How to bind string of class to resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have many tooltips saved in file hints.xaml . Like this :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp7.Theme"
                   x:Class="WpfApp7.Theme.Hints">


        <ToolTip x:Key="myToolTip" >
        <StackPanel >
            <Label Content="Nadpis" />
            <TextBlock Text="................"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ToolTip>   
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How i can bind string of class Enviroment.CurrentDictionary on my Text="................" ?

I tried to create code behind for Hints.xaml and bind by DataContext but didnt work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<StackPanel xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Label Content="Nadpis" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static system:Environment.CurrentDirectory}"/>
</StackPanel>
```