# How can i call a Method/value in Resource Dictionary file from App.xaml.cs

Tags: wpf, xaml, app.xaml

I have some .xaml file with `TextBlock` Control

```
<TextBlock Text="........." Name="myTxt" />
```

And I need on `Text` Property set value "Something" from App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static string something { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind string of class to resource dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709496/how-to-bind-string-of-class-to-resource-dictionary)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add text to a WPF Label in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902464/how-to-add-text-to-a-wpf-label-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<TextBlock xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1" Text="{x:Static local:App.something}" Name="myTxt" />
```

...provided that you change "WpfApp1" to whatever the namespace of your `App` class is:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static string something { get; set; } = "something...";
    }
}
```

Comment: @PeterTomašovič: Did you try this?